# Energy density of relativistic matter and a factor of $4$?

Tags: energy, thermal-radiation, plasma-physics

According to numerous sources (e.g. Roos, 2015 and Moore, 2013) the energy density of relativistic matter is given by:
$$u=\frac{1}{2} g^*\sigma T^4/c$$
where $g^*$ is the number of degrees of freedom present. In a universe full of photons we would have $g^*=2$ (for two possible polarizations) and therefore:
$$u=\sigma T^4/c$$
But according to Landau and Lifshitz the energy density of a photon gas is:
$$u=4\sigma T^4/c$$
so what happens to the factor of $4$?

Comment: "relativistic matter" and "radiation" are two different things, are you certain your first formula is *supposed* to work for photon gas/radiation?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Pretty sure,  Moore actually applies it to photons along with another (non-publicly available) place where I have seen this done.

Comment: I think the answer is explained here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/engrad.html